# I do not understand how to solve this

Tags: sequences-and-series

The two sequences of numbers { 1, 4, 16, 64, . . .} and { 3, 12, 48, 192, . . .} are mixed as follows: { 1, 3, 4, 12, 16, 48, 64, 192, . . .}. One of the numbers in the mixed series is 1048576. Then the number immediately preceding it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second sequence is just 3 times the previous sequence. Note that no number in the first sequence is divisible by 3 while all numbers in the second are. The mixed sequence is in the form $\{4^0, 3\cdot 4^0, 4^1, 3\cdot 4^1, 4^2, 3 \cdot 4^2, 4^3, 3 \cdot 4^3, \ldots\}$. Seeing that 1048576 is not divisible by 3 it must be from the first sequence. Looking at the mixed set you can see that each $4^k$ is preceded by $3 \cdot 4^{k - 1}$. Since $4^k = 1048576$, $3 \cdot 4^{k - 1} = \frac{3}{4} \cdot 4^k= \frac{3}{4} \cdot 1048576 = 786432$ so the preceding term is 786432 .

Answer (score 0):

The first set is $\{2^{2i}\}$, while the second set is $\{2^{2i+2}-2^{2i}\}$. Now, the number you have given is $1048576$, which is $2^{20}$. This means that the next term is the combined sequence is $2^{22}- 2^{20}$, that is, $4194304-1048576=3145728$. Done!

Comment: I made a couple of errors and had to edit to edit them. apologies...